# How to handle errors when multiple flows are running, Skip the failed flow and resume flow execution?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

How to handle errors when multiple flows are running, Skip the failed flow and resume flow execution?
I need to skip the failed flow and continue the rest part for execution

Answer (score 0):

In the PAF(pace automation Framework)we have a feature to do this .
If we put the flow in init separated by comma, it will automatically skip the failed one and continue execution.